# How to make "column3" = "column1" - "column2" in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In my sql table I have the three columns, price, costs, revenue.  I would like revenue to automatically equal price - costs  (for each separate row, not in total).  And I also would like to know how to do this all at once for existing rows.

Edit: I am using mysql

Comment: I feel stupid for asking this question, but I couldn't find anything with searching and my common sense isn't available right now for some reason

Comment: Have a look for `UPDATE` statements, or ane `SELECT` one will do with a formula in it. That's pretty easy to find

Comment: Seems like you should change `Revenue` to be a computed column. What kind of database are you using? You could also make your table only have `Costs` and `Revenue` and have a VIEW on top of that with `Revenue` added.

Comment: Please specify which database you are using ? `mysql, sql server,.. `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will update every row:

> update table_name set revenue = price - cost;

You can add a "where" clause to limit which rows are updated.  For example, to prevent setting any revenue value to a negative number:

> update table_name set revenue = price - cost where price > cost;

Comment: The problem with this solution is that if price and/or cost changes, the revenue column will not be updated accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define revenue as a computed column, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE sales ( 
price DECIMAL(5,2),  
cost DECIMAL(5,2),
revenue DECIMAL(5,2) AS (price - cost)
);
```

As per existing records if you do an alter table you will get all of them updated.